# Testing a Redux login Action with fetch api

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, testing, redux

On my React-Native project, i tried to start unit testing, how to test on Redux action that involves a login fetch api call.I've looked at some examples of testing an async Action, but I haven't wrapped my head around how to test the code below.

I've looked at using redux-mock-store, but I have no idea where to start with the test.

```js
import {
  API_URL_AUTH,
  API_URL,
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
} from "../config/consts";

import { FETCHING, FETCHED } from "../actions/ActionTypes";

const { dispatch } = this.props;
const { email, password } = this.state;

const authenticationData = {
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  grant_type: "password",
  username: email,
  password: password,
};

dispatch({ type: FETCHING });

let response = await (await fetch(API_URL_AUTH + "oauth/token", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(authenticationData),
})).json();

if (!response.error) {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("accessToken", "Bearer " + response.access_token);
  let user = await (await fetch(API_URL + "user", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + response.access_token,
    },
    method: "GET",
  })).json();
} else {
  showMessage({
    message: response.message,
    type: "danger",
  });
}

dispatch({ type: FETCHED });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Intro

First time I'm actively answering a Q on stackoverflow, I had to make an account, but here it goes.

Unit testing redux actions is all about testing collaboration. It's always smart to separate the collaboration "unit" tests from the plain ol' simple unit tests everyone knows.

## Cleaning up first

I would first abstract the fetch and locale storage calls into their own wrapper functions. That has a couple advantages:

- easier to test (collaboration functions AKA tests shouldn't do much logic, just calling other functions)
- the api is yours to control (easy to swap libraries)

```js
// api.js
import {
  API_URL_AUTH,
  API_URL,
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
} from "../config/consts";

const authenticationData = {
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  grant_type: "password",
};

export const fetchToken = ({ username, password }) => {
  return fetch(API_URL_AUTH + "oauth/token", {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ ...authenticationData, username, password }),
  })).json()
}

export fetchUser = token => fetch(API_URL + "user", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  },
  method: "GET",
})).json();

// localstorage.js
// import { AsyncStorage } from 'some-library' ???
export const storeItem = (key, value)=> AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

That makes the code of the actions much clearer and it's a bit more straight forward in what you are trying to accomplish, which ultimately will result in an easier test.

```js
// actions.js
import { fetchToken, fetchUser } from "./api";
import { storeItem } from "./localstorage";
import { FETCHING, FETCHED } from "../actions/ActionTypes";

export const loginUser = ({ username, password }) => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { signInUser, getCurrentUser }
) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCHING }); // probably needs a better action type

  try {
    const response = await fetchToken({ username, password });

    if (!response.error) {
      await storeItem ("accessToken", "Bearer " + response.access_token);
      await fetchUser(response.access_token)
    } else {
      showMessage({
        message: response.message,
        type: "danger",
      });
    }

    dispatch({ type: FETCHED }); // needs better action type
  } catch (e) {
    showMessage({
      message: response.message,
      type: "danger",
    });
  }
}
```

## Da tests

Notice that (I believe) actions in Redux are collaborator tests, which means they are the perfect fit for mocking functions, as you are only testing the interactions, not the actual logic of the functions. Simple logic functions are easy to unit test, the functions who wrap libaries (so you can control the api) usually don't get tested at all or you can write a couple integration tests, which tests the wrappers in isolation, but integrating with the library itself.

You see that by extracting logic out, the actions themselves become very straight forward and as a result make it easy to test.

One thing to notice from the testdouble library I used is that `td.when` also verifies the call. So if in your code you accidentally called `fetchToken({ email, password })` or something, the test would fail for two reasons:

1. `fetchToken` was called with the wrong arguments
2. `thenResolve` doesn't return a promise which holds `{ access_token: 'token123' }` meaning that `fetchUser` will also not be called with the correct arguments, as `access_token` would be `undefined`

```
describe('login', () => {
  let getState;
  let dependencies;
  let dispatch;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // mocking out depencies using testdouble.js (mocking library, dont pay too much attention to it
    getState = td.function('getState');
    dependencies = {
      fetchToken: td.function('fetchToken'),
      fetchUser: td.function('fetchUser'),
      storeItem: td.function('storeItem'),
    };
    dispatch = td.function('dispatch');
  });

  test('shows a message on failure, when the token could not be retrieved', () => {
    // bla
  });

  test('shows a message on failure, when the user could not be retrieved', () => {
    // bla
  });

  test('logs the user in', async () => {
    const credentials = { username: "marco@polo.com", password: '123' };
    const user = { /* some object */ }

    td.when(dependencies.fetchToken(credentials)).thenResolve({
      access_token: 'token123'
    });
    td.when(dependencies.fetchUser('token123')).thenResolve(user);

    await loginUser(credentials)(dispatch, getState, dependencies);

    td.verify(dispatch({ type: FETCHING }));
    td.verify(dispatch({ type: FETCHED }));
  });
});
```

## Closing remarks

I have gist on my github, which is another example of the same principle, since it's a common question for people on the React discord.
You can find that one here: https://gist.github.com/venikx/6e03367300f47625d5373826e86afeae

I suggest you taking a look at https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Test-Double, which is amazing resource for testing

And take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Af4M8GMoxi4 which explains these collaboration type of tests more in-depth (talks about wrapper functions, simple logic functions and how they should interact with these collaboration functions)

The most important part about your tests is isolating behavior that shouldn't break when you refactor some of the code. Tests should make it easy for you to refactor code, not harder (which is why we love wrapper functions).

## I hope that helped. Now I go back to lurking ^^